# How to change working directory in JRuby?

Tags: ruby, jruby, require, working-directory

I have to run my Ruby script from path that is higher than a script. My Ruby file is in folder *lib*. I start it in console:

```
jruby --1.9 -Clib main.rb
```

but it doesn't work correctly. It changes Dir.pwd, but require doesn't see it and another library DataMapper doesn't see it too.
I know I can add path to be seen by require by -Ilib, but it doesn't fix DataMapper issue and it is ugly I think.

Answer (score 0):

`require` loads a file from the `$LOAD_PATH`. If the directory the file you want to load is in is not on the `$LOAD_PATH`, then `require` won't find it. If you want to load a file not from the `$LOAD_PATH` but relative to the position of the currently executing file, you need to use `require_relative`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your folder structure

- app/other/some_class.rb
- app/lib/main.rb

If you navigate to the lib folder

- cd app/lib

Then run your main.rb script

- jruby main.rb

You can refer to the some_class.rb file in your main.rb script with this line

- require "../other/some_class.rb"